# Geeting CORS in API while calling inside Teams APP TAB

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

Geeting CORS in API while calling inside Teams APP TAB
Calling API in Teams App TAB

```
const u = `${domain}/api/login.json`;

  fetch(u, requestOptions)
    .then(resp => {
  }
```

While calling API we are getting CORS

[image]

Despite receiving correct responses in the network tab, the app is receiving different responses, possibly due to the restricted Teams SDK..

[image]

Comment: Please Track this issue from here-https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/geeting-cors-in-api-while-calling-inside-teams-app-tab/m-p/3944305#M8490